# Action script No such variable

Tags: apache-flex, static, members

I have a class where i have defined static members to be used as global variables within the App.

but during debugging when i try to see any class member value for that class 
I got a message "No such variable: MyClassName"

and the members can't be assigned to my values.

I use code like this

MyClassName.staticMemberName = value

Comment: What do you mean "During Debugging"?  Do you mean in the 'watch' panel of Flash Builder?  Or are you talking about some runtime behavior?  What 'members' cannot be assigned what 'values'?

Comment: Settings.Server = IP  yes i mean in the watch panel of the builder   i mean by member the Server property of the class Settings

Comment: Perhaps that 'watch' panel doesn't work with static variables. Do you ever instantiate the `Settings` class or do you just use the static properties defined in the class?

Comment: FlashBuilder generally doesn't recognize static objects anymore in its panels. It used to, but it stopped in 4.5 or 4.6.